# LM338 regulator resistor power rating

Tags: resistors, linear-regulator

How do I calculate the power rating of the two 100 milliohm resistors in this circuit?

[image: Linear regulator]

Comment: Think about where current is flowing from -> to. Helpful?

Comment: .. then apply \$P_{max}=I_{max}^2 \cdot R\$

Comment: @awjlogan Well that's what I'm trying to work out - the current path has to go via those resistors doesn't it? Let's say that the supply voltage is 40V and I'm drawing the maximum current of 10A at the output, would that not mean that those resistors need to be huge?

Comment: @JoeMann - yep, correct - a linear regulator has I_in = I_out, so you need to put the 1/2 the max current through each resistor (1/2 through each regulator). So, for 10A, this comes out at 2.5 W each. Lot of power to dissipate! You can then work out the voltage dropped across the resistors, and therefore the power dissipated by the regulators.

Comment: with Vio drop @ 3V min @ 10A = 30W loss minimum, this is not a very efficient solution.   WW in cement in metal heatsink always derate power R to desired temp.